# many draggable to many droppable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am developing an app having UI which is used for mapping fields (Source => Destination).
These fields would appear in UL -> LI -> DIV

The lists are going to be created dynamically by PHP.

Source fields are draggable with revert:true, where as Destination fields (droppable) would accept source field. I know the accept : "#divsource"

I am able to make many div's draggable, but my problem is how to define many LI->Div as droppable.

At then end the drop event would call ajax and that I can handle as well.

I am new to jQuery and whatever I have learned till now is with this task is all I know. But, my quick learning ability is not a problem.

Please help with some example.

thanks
Wikki

Below code is something I have been playing with. I know it's bit far off from what eventually it should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.srcfield').draggable({
            revert: true,
            helper: "clone" 
        });

        $('#destinationfeilds').droppable({
            accept : ".srcfield",
            over: function(){
                $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
            },
            out: function(){
                $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
            },
            drop: function(ev, ui){
                //var answer = confirm('Delete this item?');
                var theTitle = $(ui.draggable).attr("title");
                $(this).html("<u>"+theTitle+"</u><br/> is mapped!");
                //$(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
                //alert(theTitle);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="destinationfeilds" class="out">
    <span>Destination</span>
</div>

<div id="destinationfeilds" class="out">
    <span>Destination</span>
</div>
<div id="sourcefields">
    <div class="srcfield" title="First Name"><span>First Name</span></div>
    <div class="srcfield" title="Last Name"><span>Last Name</span></div>
    <div class="srcfield" title="Age"><span>Age</span></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: could you show us what you have so far?

Comment: @Andy I have some how managed to have it working, the next thing could you help on is a draggable composite div

<div class="srcfield"><span>First Name</span>
<input type="hidden" value="FirstName" id="input_1"/>
</div>

and droppable div like this

<div class="srcfield"><span>First Name</span>
<input type="hidden" value="FirstName" id="output_1"/>
<input type="hidden" value="FirstName" id="mapped_1"/>
</div>
When draggable drop on droppable i need to copy value of hiddden from input to value of hidden of mapped_1

How this can be done

thanks
wikki